# Need help with xubuntu

Tags: 16.04, xfce, live-cd, xfce-panel, xfce4-terminal

A few days ago I was using my computer perfectly fine, but now it's acting up. The computer boots up fine and loads the login screen with almost the options. I can still log in and I can still see my wallpaper, but my panel and icons are all missing. I try to right click and use keyboard commands bit I get nothing. I'm still able to access the TTY consoles, but I don't know what to do in them. I tried using the live cd to reinstall but that gets an error and tries to open a live session. The session opens but the panel and icons are gone from that too. Please help.

Comment: What is the exact error your getting?

Comment: "The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again." And when the session opens it goes to tty1, after a while it asks for Xubuntu login and I keep getting blk_update_request I/0 and SQUASHFS errors